# Find $\sqrt{{3\over2}(x-1)+\sqrt{2x^2 - 7x - 4}}, x \gt 4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

> Find
>   $$\sqrt{{3\over2}(x-1)+\sqrt{2x^2 - 7x - 4}},  x \gt 4$$

---

My attempt :-

$$3(x-1)+2\sqrt{2x^2 - 7x - 4}$$ 
$$\implies 3x - 3 + 2\sqrt{2x^2 - 7x - 4} + 2x^2 - 2x^2 -7x + 7x - 1 +1 $$
$$\implies 2x^2 -7x  - 4 + 2\sqrt{2x^2 - 7x - 4} + (- 2x^2  + 10x  + 1) $$

let $y =  \sqrt{2x^2 - 7x - 4}$

$$\therefore y^2 + 2y + (- 2x^2  + 10x  + 1)$$

solving for $y$ :-

$$y = {-2\pm \sqrt{4 - 4\times(- 2x^2  + 10x  + 1)} \over 2} $$
$$\implies y = {-1\pm \sqrt{2x^2  - 5x}} $$

---

$$\therefore y^2 + 2y + (- 2x^2  + 10x  + 1) = (y + 1 + \sqrt{2x^2  - 5x})(y + 1 - \sqrt{2x^2  - 5x})$$

$$\therefore \sqrt{{3\over2}(x-1)+\sqrt{2x^2 - 7x - 4}} = \sqrt{(y + 1 + \sqrt{2x^2  - 5x})(y + 1 - \sqrt{2x^2  - 5x})\over 2}$$

Sadly this does not remove the square root.

---

So the question is how can i factorize $3(x-1)+2\sqrt{2x^2 - 7x - 4}$ to remove that square root ?

just some hints are fine with me, thanks.

Comment: What do you want to find? Your function is just a function whose domain of definition is $x\ge 4$ Do you mean simplify maybe?

Comment: @Piquito Sorry, yes i meant simplify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sqrt{{3\over2}(x-1)+\sqrt{2x^2 - 7x - 4}}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{3(x-1)+2\sqrt{2x^2 - 7x - 4}}2}=$$
$$=\sqrt\frac{\color{red}{3x-3}+2\sqrt{(2x+1)(x-4)}}2=$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{\color{red}{2x+1}+2\sqrt{(2x+1)(x-4)}+\color{red}{x-4}}2}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{(\sqrt{2x+1}+\sqrt{x-4})^2}2}=$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{2x+1}+\sqrt{x-4}}{\sqrt2}$$

Comment: Now i know why hardest problems have simplest answers. $\ddot \smile$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $2 x^2 - 7 x - 4 = (2x+1)(x-4)$, so you may guess that the desired result is of the form $a \sqrt{2x+1} + b \sqrt{x-4}$.  Now square that, and see what $a$ and $b$ would give you $\dfrac{3}{2}(x-1) + \sqrt{2x^2-7x-4}$.